# 100% width div in ie8 wont allow for browser window size

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

So my problem is this: I have a page (http://www.dukeblogger.com/allergan/) and on this page there is a div containing three images that are clickable to show content below. I cant seem to get all 3 images to fit on the same line in ie8. It works fine in firefox but the ie8 window does not seem to accommodate the width at all.

http://i.share.pho.to/f7d11541_o.png

Comment: Did you try to use `float: left` in the links?

Comment: Would that help? i want them centered on the page

Comment: I tried to float them left and it broke the page pretty much

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your zoom level is at 100%?

Hit ctrl+0 to make sure

Comment: I'm looking at it in browserstack and it looks wrong. I can take a screen shot if that helps

Comment: Try checking on a real machine. It opened up fine (all images in same line) on my Internet Explorer (version 11 tough). I also tried on Browserstack however here it showed the same output(last image displaced) for all the three browsers Firefox,Chrome,IE8. Emulation can go wrong.